# Is it possible to pass my own props when using @reach/router with Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, reach-router, gatsby-plugin

I'm trying to pass my own custom props, (functions, objects ..etc) but they are not passing, when I try @reach/router without gatsby it works fine though.

My app.js:

```
      <Router basepath="">
        <Welcome path="" />
        <OtherComponent
          path="/comppath"
          myprop="prop data"
        />
      </Router>
```

my OtherComponent.js

```
export default function OtherComponent(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My Component</h1>
            {props.myprop}
        </div>
    );
}
```

the component render fine, but my prop is not passing, when I console log props I only get the path, location, pageContext and the navigate method ..etc but not my prop

side note: I'm using gatsby's gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths

Answer (score 2):

With `<Link>` component (extended by React's `@reach/router`) you can pass a `state` object which can include whatever you want.

`<Link>` component indeed it's a wrapper of `@reach/router` that adds useful enhancements specific to Gatsby. All props are passed through to `@reach/router`’s `<Link>` component. Applied to your code:

```
<Link
  to={`/comppath`}
  state={{ myProp: 'hello'}}
>
```

Then in your `OtherComponent`, you will need to check for: `location.state.myProp` which will have `hello` as a value.

To pass a `props`, you just need to change `hello` for your object:

```
  state={{ myProp: props }}
```

You can check for further information in [Gatsby Link API documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but what if I want to pass props directly to a component in the last example of this page https://reach.tech/router/api/RouteComponent ?

Comment: You can change the `hello` string for your `props` object